# Nonlinear Role Hierarchy using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Im trying to implement a structure that has a "nonlinear" role Hierarchy using Spring Security (Boot Starter).

To explain it better, imagine the following case:

**Roles:**

- President
- Human Resources Director
- IT Director
- Assistant
- Technician

**Role Hierarchy:**

- Human Resources Director > Assistant
- IT Director > Technician

Now the problem:

- President > Human Resources Director

AND

- President > IT Director

When I register the Role Hierarchy using

```
roleHierarchy.setRoleHierarchy("PRESIDENT>HUMAN_RESOURCES_DIRECTOR");
roleHierarchy.setRoleHierarchy("PRESIDENT>IT_DIRECTOR");
```

It only records "PRESIDENT> IT_DIRECTOR".

This may be because I might have misuderstood Spring Security Role Hierarchy.

Whatever is the case, how could I apply it so that my "President" can access both role permissions without adding extensive manual authorizations?

---

**Edit:**

Just to clarify, all examples I found follow a linear Hierarchy such as

President > IT Director

IT Director > Technician

---

**Edit 2:**

From Spring Security Debug, when implementing this nonlinear role hierarchy the way it was exposed, I get a message similar to:

```
getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_PRESIDENT] one can reach [ROLE_PRESIDENT, ROLE_IT_DIRECTOR] in zero or more steps.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the understanding of the method "setRoleHierarchy".

The method sets the Role Hierarchy, not adds it.

In order do what is wanted, there's the need to "concatenate" the hierarchies, as such:

```
String hierarchy = "ROLE_PRESIDENT > ROLE_IT_DIRECTOR "+"ROLE_PRESIDENT > ROLE_HUMAN_RESOURCES_DIRECTOR"; // Or write it straight up
roleHierarchy.setRoleHierarchy(hierarchy);
```